# Servo position is always changing

Tags: gsm, servo

When I send an SMS like this:

> Tilt:090
>
> Azimuth:120

First time an SMS is read, the servo rotates to the correct position, but after they change a small angle, it's like noise.

I do following things to stop that change:

- First try with motor driver
- Capacitor circuit use

Here is my code:

```c++
#include <AFMotor.h>
#include <Sim800l.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <Servo.h>

Sim800l Sim800l; //to declare the library
Servo Tilt;
Servo Azimuth;

String text; // to storage the text of the sms
uint8_t index; // to indicate the message to read.
int t, pos, old_pos, pos1, old_pos1; // to indicate the int value.

void setup()
{
    Tilt.attach(9); // attaches the servo on pin 5 to the servoH object
    Azimuth.attach(10); // attaches the servo on pin 6 to the servoV object
    Serial.begin(9600); // only for debug the results .
    Sim800l.begin(); // initializate the library.
    index = 1; //  position in the prefered memory storage.
}

void Tilt_servo()
{
    if (old_pos > pos) {
        for (int q = old_pos; q > pos; q--) {
            Tilt.write(q);
            delay(20);
            Serial.println("position dicreasing");
        }
    }
    else if (old_pos < pos) {
        for (int q = old_pos; q < pos; q++) {
            Tilt.write(q);
            delay(20);
            Serial.println("position increasing");
        }
    }
    else {
        Tilt.write(pos);
    }
}

void Azimuth_servo()
{
    if (old_pos1 > pos1) {
        for (int d = old_pos1; d > pos1; d--) {
            Azimuth.write(d);
            delay(20);
            Serial.println("position1 dicreasing");
        }
    }
    else if (old_pos < pos) {
        for (int d = old_pos1; d < pos1; d++) {
            Azimuth.write(d);
            delay(20);
            Serial.println("position1 increasing");
        }
    }
    else {
        Azimuth.write(pos1);
    }
}

void loop()
{
    delay(1000);

    Serial.println("---------------------------------------------------------------------------");
    old_pos = pos;
    old_pos1 = pos1;

    Serial.println("old_pos:");
    Serial.println(old_pos);
    Serial.println("old_pos1:");
    Serial.println(old_pos1);

    text = Sim800l.readSms(index);
    Serial.println(text);
    String W = text.substring(33, 45); // filter phone number...
    Serial.println(W);
    String y = text.substring(20, 30); // filter REC UNREAD
    Serial.println(y);

    if (y == "REC UNREAD") {

        String s = text.substring(74, 79); // filter the "Tilt:"
        Serial.println(s);
        String p = text.substring(79, 82); // filter the position
        int t = p.toInt(); // convert position as int value
        Serial.println(t);
        pos = t;

        String v = text.substring(83, 91); // filter the "Azimuth:" letter
        Serial.println(v);
        String u = text.substring(91, 94); // filter the position as string
        int b = u.toInt(); // convert position as int value
        Serial.println(b);
        pos1 = b;

        if (s == "Tilt:" && v == "Azimuth:") {

            Tilt_servo();
            delay(1000);
            Serial.println("done....Tilt...");
            Serial.println(pos);
            Azimuth_servo();
            delay(1000);
            Serial.println("done....Azimuth...");
            Serial.println(pos1);
        }
        //Sim800l.delAllSms();
        //delay(5000);
    }

    else {
        Tilt.write(pos);
        Azimuth.write(pos1);
    }

    delay(1000);
    Sim800l.delAllSms();
    delay(5000);
    Serial.println("---------------------------------------------------------------------------");
}
```

Comment: you need to start troubleshooting by writing minimal code that positions one servo, holds position for a second or so, then positions servo to another point and holds again .... test all servos that way

Comment: i tested all servo.then they all work correctly. but above code running it start the same problem

Comment: comment out lines like this `Serial.println("position1 dicreasing");` ... see if that may clear it up ... btw, the word is "decreasing"

Comment: i tested. in these two lines executed that error happen.so it can be affect sim800l library.    text = Sim800l.readSms(index); and Sim800l.delAllSms();